# In which East European country in the 1980s did people put their TVs in front of windows and turn them facing outside?

Tags: europe, propaganda, 1980s

Years ago, I read an article about the period during which regime changes happened in Eastern European countries in the late 1980s and early 1990s. It was mentioned in the article that, in one of those countries, citizens began to put their TVs in front of the windows to give the message that the propaganda and false news no longer worked. Which country was it?

I don't need a source, but it would be great if someone included one in their answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At last I found the answer to my question.

The country is **Poland**, the city is **Gdansk** and the year is **1981**.

> In Gdansk, there were the black TV screens. People there began moving their television sets to the windows-with the screens pointed out to the street. They were sending a sign to one another, and the government. We, too, refuse to watch. We also reject your version of truth.

From the book "The Elements of Journalism : What newspeople should know and the public should expect / Bill Kovach & Tom Rosenstiel"

The source: [Library of Congress](http://catdir.loc.gov/catdir/samples/random043/00047450.html)

Answer (score 2):

Not 100% sure, but here is something to look into. Hungary had a regime change in 1989, moving to a non-communist government. During the revolution, protests frequently occurred at state TV headquarters. Furthermore, this could be a very Hungarian thing to protest, as in 2018 these anti-state TV sentiments happened again.

Sources:

- [Wikipedia:Revolutions of 1989](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutions_of_1989)
- [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-hungary-protest/hungarians-protest-at-state-tv-to-demand-independent-public-media-courts-idUSKBN1OG0RE)